# WSO2AS Soapcall of service returns null

Tags: php, soap, wso2

I'm developing a web-app, which needs data from a database.
For the communication with the db I use WSO2AS.

I made a database and linked that to the data service created, when i test the service in the admin panel of WSO2, I get the data needed from the database.

The data service I created is called TestService.

[image: WSO2AS data service test response]

Now I want to have the same response in my php template as well, using this code.

```
<?php 
    try {
        $client = new SoapClient('http://192.168.178.12:9763/services/TestService?wsdl');
        $result =  $client->__soapCall('greet');
        printf("Result = %s\r\n", $result->return);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        printf("Message = %s\r\n",$e->__toString());
    }
?>
```

But this gives NULL, when I try to dump the $result.

When I try to execute an example WSO2 created, I do get the right result. While the soapcall code is the same, only the service name is different.

```
<?php
    try {
       $client = new SoapClient('http://192.168.178.12:9763/services/HelloService?wsdl');
       $result =  $client->__soapCall('greet', array(array('name' => 'Sam')));
       printf("Result = %s\r\n", $result->return);

   } catch (Exception $e) {
       printf("Message = %s\r\n",$e->__toString());
   }
?>
```

This code returns "Hello Sam !!!".

So I wonder what I did wrong, I personally think I made a mistake in implementing the service itself, but can't find it.

If any more information is needed feel free to ask, hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to have arguments in your soapcall.

After calling this __soapCall('greet', array());

It gave the proper response.